# Expect Winning after 100 trials

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, expected-value, games

I came across this interesting question in a game forum and I couldn't solve it:

Each time a gamer has probability = 1/4 of drawing out an SSR, if the gamer doesn't get an SSR after 3 consecutive draws, the 4th draw is guaranteed to be an SSR. What is the expect number of SSRs after 100 draws?

Comment: What is "SSR"?????

Comment: @kjetil b halvorsen   it doesnt really matter, but in the game community, it stands for super super rare (card)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest approaching it as a Markov Reward Process with 4 states.

The transition probabilities $P$ between them are:

| state | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.25 | 0.75 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 0.25 | 0 | 0.75 | 0 |
| 3 | 0.25 | 0 | 0 | 0.75 |
| 4 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

And the rewards $\vec{r}$ for reaching each state are:

| state | reward |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 |

Logic:

- Given a system in state 1, 2 or 3, if no SSR is drawn the system progresses to the next one with no reward.
- Given a system in state 1, 2 or 3, if a SSR is drawn the system gets to state 1 with 1 reward.
- Given a system in state 4, the transition to state 1 and the consecutive reward of 1 is guaranteed.

Given a single step the value $\vec{v}$ of each state is:
$$
\vec{v}_1=P\cdot\vec{r}
$$

Given two steps:
$$
\vec{v}_1=P\cdot\vec{r}
$$
$$
\vec{v}_2=P\cdot(\vec{v}_1+\vec{r})
$$
And so on, iteratively.

Following this logic $\vec{v}_{100}$ is:

| state | expected reward |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 36.3571918367348 |
| 2 | 36.5114775510204 |
| 3 | 36.7171918367347 |
| 4 | 36.9914775510203 |

The value we care about is the first one, since we start with no previous attempts.

This MATLAB code can be used to test the result:

```
function v = evaluate(n)

v = zeros(n, 1);
state = ones(n, 1);
for i = 1:n
    for j = 1:100
        if state(i) == 4
            v(i) = v(i) + 1;
            state(i) = 1;
        else
            if rand <= 0.25
                v(i) = v(i) + 1;
                state(i) = 1;
            else
                state(i) = state(i) + 1;
            end
        end
    end
end
v = mean(v);

end
```

Testing with $n=1000000$ gives:
$$
\vec{v}_{100}=36.3665300000000
$$