# flipping card with increasing probability

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, games

In an online game you can buy cards which has a 5% probability to be rare cards. If you don't have the rare card for more than 20 times, the chance of next purchase will increase by 5%, repeat until it becomes 100%. If you have the rare card the probability will reset to default.

Question: what's the chance of having m rare cards in n attempts?

Is there any way to avoid listing possible permutations directly?

Comment: i think this requires the self-study tag.

Comment: Related to the negative binomial distribution with varying probabilities.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expect Winning after 100 trials](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/334002/expect-winning-after-100-trials)